Financial Services Cloud: Manual rollup of AUM fails in test class, FinServ__Household__c is null
I have the follow Apex class, which works fine when run from Anonymous apex. I tried in sandbox with one record, and full copy sandbox with 30,000 records, and got the results expected with no errors:
global class FinancialAccountAUM implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // Query for Accounts with Record Type Household or Person Account
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Account 
            WHERE RecordType.Name IN ('Household', 'Person')
        ]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
        Set<Id> householdIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> personAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

        //Collect Account IDs based on record type
        for(Account acc : scope) {
            if(acc.RecordType.Name == 'Household') {
                householdIds.add(acc.Id);
            } else if (acc.RecordType.Name == 'Person') {
                personAccountIds.add(acc.Id);
            }
        }

        System.debug('Household IDs: ' + householdIds);
        System.debug('Person Account IDs: ' + personAccountIds);

        //Query financial accounts for all collected account IDs
        List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__c> financialAccounts = [
            SELECT Name, FinServ__Balance__c, FinServ__Household__c, FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c
            FROM FinServ__FinancialAccount__c
            WHERE FinServ__Household__c IN :householdIds OR FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c IN :personAccountIds
        ];

        System.debug('Financial Accounts: ' + financialAccounts);

        //Maps to hold the sum of balances
        Map<Id, Decimal> householdBalances = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
        Map<Id, Decimal> personBalances = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

        //Sum balances for each financial account
        for (FinServ__FinancialAccount__c finAcc : financialAccounts) {
            if (finAcc.FinServ__Household__c != null && householdIds.contains(finAcc.FinServ__Household__c)) {
                if (!householdBalances.containsKey(finAcc.FinServ__Household__c)) {
                    householdBalances.put(finAcc.FinServ__Household__c, 0);
                }
                householdBalances.put(finAcc.FinServ__Household__c, householdBalances.get(finAcc.FinServ__Household__c) + (finAcc.FinServ__Balance__c != null ? finAcc.FinServ__Balance__c : 0));
            } if (finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c != null && personAccountIds.contains(finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c)) {
                if (!personBalances.containsKey(finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c)) {
                    personBalances.put(finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c, 0);
                }
                personBalances.put(finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c, personBalances.get(finAcc.FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c) + (finAcc.FinServ__Balance__c != null ? finAcc.FinServ__Balance__c : 0));
            }
        }

        System.debug('Household Balances: ' + householdBalances);
        System.debug('Person Balances: ' + personBalances);

        //Create list of Accounts to update
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(Id accountId : householdBalances.keySet()) {
            accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
                Id = accountId,
                Total_Household_AUM__c = householdBalances.get(accountId)
            ));
        }
        for(id accountId : personBalances.keySet()) {
            accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
                Id = accountId,
                Total_Individual_AUM__c = personBalances.get(accountId)
            ));
        }

        if(!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update accountsToUpdate;
            System.debug('Updated Accounts: ' + accountsToUpdate);
        }
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NUmberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        system.debug('job === ' +job);
    }
}

I then attempted to write the following test class:
@isTest
public class FinancialAccountAUMTest {

    @TestSetup
    static void setupData(){
        // create household
        Account newHousehold = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Household',
            Servicing_Location__c = 'Roswell',
            AccountSource = 'Event',
            Type = 'Client',
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert newHousehold;

        // create person account
        Account newPerson = new Account(
            firstName = 'first',
            lastName = 'last',
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert newPerson;

        //create the financial account
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__c finAcct1 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__c(
            FinServ__Balance__c = 100,
            Name = '11111111',
            FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = newPerson.Id,
            FinServ__Household__c = newHousehold.Id,
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.FinServ__FinancialAccount__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Investment Account').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert finAcct1;
        system.debug('finAcct1 === ' +finAcct1);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testBatchExecution() {

        // Query initial household and person account balances
        Account household = [SELECT Id, Total_Household_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Household' LIMIT 1];
        Account personAccount = [SELECT Id, Total_Individual_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Person' LIMIT 1];

        System.debug('Initial household AUM: ' + household.Total_Household_AUM__c);
        System.debug('Initial person AUM: ' + personAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c);
        
        Test.startTest();
        FinancialAccountAUM batch = new FinancialAccountAUM();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Query updated household and person account balances
        Account updatedHousehold = [SELECT Id, Total_Household_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :household.Id];
        Account updatedPersonAccount = [SELECT Id, Total_Individual_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :personAccount.Id];

        System.debug('Updated household AUM: ' + updatedHousehold.Total_Household_AUM__c);
        System.debug('Updated person AUM: ' + updatedPersonAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c);
 
        System.assertEquals(100, updatedHousehold.Total_Household_AUM__c, 'Household AUM should be 100');
        System.assertEquals(100, updatedPersonAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c, 'Individual AUM should be 100');
    }
    
}

But my test class fails with the following error:

System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Household AUM should be 100:
Expected: 100, Actual: null

Here's the log from attempting to run the test class:

You can see that in when I insert the Financial Account in the test class, it has a FinServ__Household__c value, but when I execute the batch class, the debug shows that the FinServ__Household__c value appears to be null.
And here's the segment of the code that isn't covered by the test class:

Can anyone help me figure out why the Household value is going null and/or anything else to try?

I'm not familiar with the Financial Services cloud, but page 1013 of the FinServ Developer Guide (Rollup SObjects) indicates that a before insert trigger on FinServ__FinancialAccount__c is updating the Household__c field based on "the account portion of the group that it's rolling up to". So it sounds to me like you need to be doing some additional setup. Exactly what that setup would be, I can't say (due to my total lack of experience).

Derek F. led me down the path to figuring out what was wrong. In the test class, I needed to explicitly create the AccountContactRelation between the Household account and the Person Account, and then also within @testSetup add a block of code to enable group record rollups. After I did that, the test passed with 100% code coverage. Updated code below.
Test Class:
@isTest
public class FinancialAccountAUMTest {

    @TestSetup
    static void setupData(){
        
        TestUtilities.enablePersonConfiguration();
        
        // create household
        Account newHousehold = new Account(
            Name = 'Test Household',
            Servicing_Location__c = 'Roswell',
            AccountSource = 'Event',
            Type = 'Client',
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert newHousehold;

        // create person account
        Account newPerson = new Account(
            firstName = 'first',
            lastName = 'last',
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert newPerson;

        Contact newPersonContact = [ SELECT Id FROM Contact where AccountId = :newPerson.id ];

        // create account contact relation
        AccountContactRelation newAcr = new AccountContactRelation(
            accountId = newHousehold.id,
            contactId = newPersonContact.id,
            FinServ__PrimaryGroup__c = true,
            FinServ__Primary__c = true,
            FinServ__Rollups__c = 'Tasks;Events;Financial Accounts;Assets and Liabilities;Financial Goals;Referrals;All',
            IsActive = true,
            Roles = 'Member'
        );
        insert newAcr;

        newPerson.Household__pc = newHousehold.Id;
        update newPerson;

        //create the financial account
        FinServ__FinancialAccount__c finAcct1 = new FinServ__FinancialAccount__c(
            FinServ__Balance__c = 100,
            Name = '11111111',
            FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c = newPerson.Id,
            FinServ__Household__c = newHousehold.Id,
            OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(),
            recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.FinServ__FinancialAccount__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Investment Account').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert finAcct1;
        system.debug('finAcct1 === ' +finAcct1);
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testBatchExecution() {

        // Query initial household and person account balances
        Account household = [SELECT Id, Total_Household_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Household' LIMIT 1];
        Account personAccount = [SELECT Id, Total_Individual_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Person' LIMIT 1];

        System.debug('Initial household AUM: ' + household.Total_Household_AUM__c);
        System.debug('Initial person AUM: ' + personAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c);
        
        Test.startTest();
        FinancialAccountAUM batch = new FinancialAccountAUM();
        Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Query updated household and person account balances
        Account updatedHousehold = [SELECT Id, Total_Household_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :household.Id];
        Account updatedPersonAccount = [SELECT Id, Total_Individual_AUM__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :personAccount.Id];

        System.debug('Updated household AUM: ' + updatedHousehold.Total_Household_AUM__c);
        System.debug('Updated person AUM: ' + updatedPersonAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c);
 
        System.assertEquals(100, updatedHousehold.Total_Household_AUM__c, 'Household AUM should be 100');
        System.assertEquals(100, updatedPersonAccount.Total_Individual_AUM__c, 'Individual AUM should be 100');
    }
    
}

Utility Class:
public with sharing class TestUtilities {

     public static void enablePersonConfiguration() {
        
        // enable group record rollups
        FinServ__WealthAppConfig__c wealthAppConfig = new FinServ__WealthAppConfig__c();
        wealthAppConfig.FinServ__ReferrerScoreCalcEnabled__c = true;
        wealthAppConfig.FinServ__EnableGroupRecordRollups__c = true;
        wealthAppConfig.FinServ__EnableBusinessReferralsMade__c = true;
        wealthAppConfig.FinServ__EnableRollupSummary__c = true;
        wealthAppConfig.SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
        insert wealthAppConfig;
        
        // add person account config
        FinServ__UsePersonAccount__c personAccountConfig = new FinServ__UsePersonAccount__c();
        personAccountConfig.Name = 'Use Person Account';
        personAccountConfig.FinServ__Enable__c = true;
        insert personAccountConfig;
    }

}


Could you add in a concrete example of what you did? Having a textual description is ok, but having a code example along with that would increase this answer's usefulness (most of the traffic on questions comes from other people with the same or a similar issue).
